# Coping value of one column entry to another of same record ,If the value is null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have two columns in my table . Code and DocEntery . If DocEntry has value 'NULL' I want it to change to the value of corresponding 'Code' value .There are many rows so could you tell me any query that can be used to update the complete table ?  I am using SQL server.

Comment: Update Table set DocEntry = Code Where DocEntry IS NULL
If 'NULL' means the varchar contains NULL then you need to change the where clause of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to update the enitre table or use any sort of `CASE EXPRESSION` or `IF`, just filter only those will `NULL` values, and update all of them:

```
UPDATE YourTable t
SET t.DocEntry = t.Code
WHERE t.DocEntry is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
Update table1 set DocEntry = (Case when DocEntry is NULL then Code Else DocEntry end)
```